# Why are there drastically different memory locations for char arrays vs character pointers on macOS?

Tags: c, memory

I'm brushing up on my C by printing out the addresses for a character array vs. a character pointer:

```
int main() {
    char stringa[] = "";
    char *stringp = "";
    char *stringp2 = "a";


    printf ("%p\n", stringa);
    printf ("%p\n", stringp);
    printf ("%p\n", stringp2);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0x7ff7b07ca1fb
0x10f738fa4
0x10f738fa5
```

I was surprised to see that the character arrays are stored in a different part of the computer's memory compared to the pointers.

Comment: There isn't a different location for the pointer, but rather for the thing it points to.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, they are.

1. `stringa` is an automatic storage duration object and it is allocated on the stack
2. `stringp` & `stringp2` are referencing **string literals** which are stored in a completely different memory segment (usually it is called `.rodata` and it is read-ony).

If you add:

```
    printf ("%p\n", (void *)&stringp);
    printf ("%p\n", (void *)&stringp2);
```

you will see that the pointers are also stored on the stack as they have automatic storage duration

You have also static and dynamic storage duration objects and they will be stored in different areas of memory.

```
int main() {
    char stringa[] = "";
    static char stringb[] = "";
    char *stringp2 = "a";
    char *ptr = malloc(5);


    printf ("%p\n", (void *)stringa);
    printf ("%p\n", (void *)stringb);
    printf ("%p\n", (void *)stringp2);
    printf ("%p\n", (void *)&stringp2);
    printf ("%p\n", (void *)ptr);
    return 0;
}
```